# linux sysctl tunable knob kernel.yama.ptrace_scope

Tags: linux, kernel, sysctl

The [reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) lists as values 0,1,2,3.

Today I tried it on two servers :

1. kernel 3.0.0

> sysctl -w kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=3
>
> error: "Invalid argument" setting key "kernel.yama.ptrace_scope"

2. kernel 4.9.38

> sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope
>
> error: "kernel.yama.ptrace_scope" is an unknown key

Where can I get this tunable change history ?
Is it replaced by a new name in recent kernels ?

Is the old *kernel.yama.protected_sticky_symlinks* renamed to *fs.protected_symlinks* ?

Comment: Do these systems have anything in the directory `/proc/sys/kernel/yama` ? If not, then they may not have been configured with yama (it's optional).

Comment: The 4.9.38, Amazon AMI instance, hasn't */proc/sys/kernel/yama*

Comment: The 3.0.0 supports yama : I can set the values 0 and 1.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yama patches were around as of 2.6, and made it into the mainstream kernel in [3.4](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.4/source/security/yama/yama_lsm.c), where `ptrace_scope` had an allowable range of [0,1]. In [3.5](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.5/source/security/yama/yama_lsm.c), `ptrace_scope` had an allowable range of [0,3].

Comment: @Mark, if you make an answer I will upvote.

Comment: @Mark : optional : I read the two sources but I don't understand : kernel 3.4, enabling ptrace_scope = 1 : is it equivalent to a value (1,2,3) of kernel 3.5 ?

Comment: I don't have the answers to your other questions yet (change history and history of particular sysctl variables.) ptrace_scope = 1 means the same in both 3.4 and 3.5. And ptrace_scope = 0 means the same in both 3.4 and 3.5.